# Using lowercase function on list (Python3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Simple question here:

I have a DF like this

```
 KW              Score     Group     Size
a big man         7          2        1
Purple cow        3          4        2
for all is Not    2          3        3
There we go       2          1        3
...
Day Late          1          3        2
```

I want to convert all characters in the KW column to lowercase but my code doesn't seem to work.  I'm sure it's something very obvious but what am I doing wrong?

```
df = xl.parse()
df.head()
df.KW.str.lower()
df1 = df[['KW','Score','Group','Size']]
```

Comment: Are you assigning the result of your operation to a new column or in fact to anything? Your line of code should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is but it should work, you are possibly not assigning the result of the operation to anything:

```
In [3]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'KW':['Upper case', 'lower case','ALL CAPS']})
df


Out[3]:
           KW
0  Upper case
1  lower case
2    ALL CAPS
In [6]:

df['cleaned'] = df.KW.str.lower()
df
Out[6]:
           KW     cleaned
0  Upper case  upper case
1  lower case  lower case
2    ALL CAPS    all caps
```

Comment: Seemed to clear it up -- I ended up assigning it to a new column as you suggested

Comment: done!  but my question is why does it need to be assigned to something in the first place?

Comment: because it doesn't work in place, it returns a copy of the column with the operation applied. In general almost all pandas operations return a copy.